# Is there a way to only execute part of a WHERE statement based on data in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Is there a way to only execute part of a WHERE statement perhaps using some sort of IF-THEN statement based on data in the database?

The code below displays scheduled tasks for a specific date correctly in most cases, but there is an anomaly. If someone creates a task and then sets a start date before the date they created it, the task won't show up even though it is scheduled on that day.

In this example, we only want to use the create date (i.e. `TaskCreated <= '" . $DisplayDateTime . "'"`) if the start date is not set (i.e. `TaskStartDate = '' OR TaskStartDate is NULL'`) If the `TaskStartDate` is set, then we want to use that date instead of the create date for the date range.

```
// Displays tasks that are scheduled on a particular date or marked as "focus"
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Reminders";
$sql = $sql . " " . "WHERE TaskUserID = " . $loggedinuser;
$sql = $sql . " " . "AND ( TaskFocus = 1";
$sql = $sql . " " . "OR ( TaskCreated <= '" . $DisplayDateTime . "'";
$sql = $sql . " " . "AND ( TaskStartDate <= '" . $DisplayDate . "' OR TaskStartDate = '' OR TaskStartDate is NULL )";
$sql = $sql . " " . "AND ( TaskPauseDate <= '" . $DisplayDate . "' OR TaskPauseDate = '' OR TaskPauseDate is NULL )";
$sql = $sql . " " . "AND ( TaskSchedDate >= '" . $DisplayDate . "' AND TaskSchedDate is NOT NULL )" ;
$sql = $sql . " " . "AND ( TaskDueDate <> '" . $DisplayDate . "'  OR TaskDueDate = '' OR TaskDueDate is NULL )";                            
$sql = $sql . " " . ") )";
$sql = $sql . " " . "AND ( TaskPauseDate <= '" . $DisplayDate . "' OR TaskPauseDate = '' OR TaskPauseDate is NULL )";
$sql = $sql . " " . "ORDER BY TaskFocus DESC, TaskPriority ASC, TaskSchedDate ASC, TaskDueDate ASC";
```

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Reminders 
   WHERE TaskUserID = 1 
   AND ( ( TaskCreated <= '2020-12-03 23:59:59' 
      AND ( TaskStartDate <= '2020-12-03' OR TaskStartDate = '' OR TaskStartDate is NULL ) 
      AND ( TaskPauseDate <= '2020-12-03' OR TaskPauseDate = '' OR TaskPauseDate is NULL ) 
      AND ( TaskSchedDate >= '2020-12-03' AND TaskSchedDate is NOT NULL ) 
      AND ( TaskDueDate >= '2020-12-03' OR TaskDueDate = '' OR TaskDueDate is NULL ) ) ) 
   AND ( TaskPauseDate <= '2020-12-03' OR TaskPauseDate = '' OR TaskPauseDate is NULL ) 
   ORDER BY TaskFocus DESC, TaskPriority ASC, TaskSchedDate ASC, TaskDueDate ASC
```

How is the best way to fix that anomaly?

Comment: I think an `OR` should be able to do that

Comment: You're fixing it at the wrong end. You should ensure that invalid states never make it to the database. How to try and fix the corrupted entries is entirely up to you, but I'd suggest just running a query that copies created date into start date.

Comment: @El_Vanja The start date being empty is not a corrupt entry. Not all tasks have a start and end date. The data is valid.

Comment: I'm talking about this part: _"...and then sets a start date before the date they created it.."_ - that sort of update should be prevented.

Comment: Put the optional parts as `or` bits... or build the query dynamically. Also, don't write queries like this. Prepared statements with parameterized queries.

Comment: @Manav Can you be more specific? I have tried an OR statement and that does not work either. 
```
$sql = $sql . " " . "OR ( ( TaskCreated <= '" . $DisplayDateTime . "'";
$sql = $sql . " " . "OR TaskStartDate <= '" . $DisplayDate . "' )";
```

Comment: @El_Vanja Setting a start date before the entry is created is perfectly valid. The create date is automatically generated and says when that record was created. It has nothing to do with when the task starts and ends. We only reference the create date if someone sets a scheduled date, but not a start date so that we don't get every task without a start date..

Comment: I see. Sorry for the confusion. I automatically assumed one could not create a task retrospectively.

Comment: Take a look to my answer.

Comment: @El_Vanja It doesn't happen often, but sometimes a user wants to record that a meeting or task happened earlier and wants the correct dates. Also, imported tasks might not have accurate create dates or a create date at all (so the create date winds up being the imported date). We can't assume the create date is before the start date.

Comment: Could do `coalesce(NULLIF(TaskStartDate, ''), '2020-12-03')` and that will make the NULL and empty `TaskStartDate`s set to the oldest dates

Comment: Why there are $DisplayDateTime and $DisplayDate ?  $DisplayDate is not enough ?

Comment: @Florent Because the TaskCreateDate is a datetime and both TaskStartDate and $DisplayDate are just dates which default to 2020-12-03 00:00:00 (if the date is 2020-12-03) which means anything created after 00:00:00 won't appear. To make it work properly, I made the time 23:59:59 and assigned it to $DisplayDateTime.

Comment: You can use DATE(TaskCreated) to convert datetime to date.

Comment: @user3783243 That might work. Thanks to all of your input, I did find a solution that worked. And good point about the prepared statements. For this particular query, all of the variables are sanitized elsewhere before this is called, but I should just incorporate that checking into the query as well.

Comment: Thank you all. You really helped me figure it out. Even if no one has provided the correct answer, all of your input helped me think it through and try some variations of what you proposed. It turned out to need an additional OR statement in there.

Comment: @Florent Thanks. That probably would have been easier. :) I'll do that next time.

Comment: Just realized the fix I thought worked did not work.

Comment: Actually, it turned out it needed this: AND ( ( ( TaskCreated <= '2020-12-03 23:59:59' OR ( TaskStartDate <= '2020-12-03' OR TaskStartDate = '' OR TaskStartDate is NULL ) )

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing `TaskCreated <= '" . $DisplayDateTime . "'"`

with

`((TaskCreated <= '" . $DisplayDateTime . "') OR (TaskStartDate = '' OR TaskStartDate is NULL'))"`

Comment: That didn;t work but from your answer, I figured out what did. It is $sql = $sql . " " . "( ( ( TaskCreated <= '" . $DisplayDateTime . "') OR ( TaskStartDate <= '" . $DisplayDate . "' ) )";

Comment: Actually, it turned out it needed this: AND ( ( ( TaskCreated <= '2020-12-03 23:59:59' OR ( TaskStartDate <= '2020-12-03' OR TaskStartDate = '' OR TaskStartDate is NULL ) )

Answer (score 1):

The sql  in PHP HEREDOC string. (easier to read)

```
$sql = <<<WXC
SELECT * FROM Reminders 
WHERE    TaskUserID = $loggedinuser
    AND (   (( TaskStartDate <= '{$DisplayDate}' and (TaskStartDate <> '' AND TaskStartDate is NOT NULL ))
            OR  (TaskCreated <= '{$DisplayDateTime}' AND ( TaskStartDate is NULL OR TaskStartDate = '' )  ))
        AND ( TaskPauseDate <= '{$DisplayDate}' OR TaskPauseDate = '' OR TaskPauseDate is NULL )
        AND ( TaskSchedDate >= '{$DisplayDate}' AND TaskSchedDate is NOT NULL )
        AND ( TaskDueDate <> '{$DisplayDate}'  OR TaskDueDate = '' OR TaskDueDate is NULL )  
        AND ( TaskPauseDate <= '{$DisplayDate}' OR TaskPauseDate = '' OR TaskPauseDate is NULL ))
ORDER BY TaskFocus DESC, TaskPriority ASC, TaskSchedDate ASC, TaskDueDate ASC
WXC;
//
```

Comment: Instead of displaying the missing entries, this removed the entries that already showed up. Now getting 0 results.

Comment: Thanks to your input, I figured out what works and you are close. It needed the following change: $sql = $sql . " " . "( ( ( TaskCreated <= '" . $DisplayDateTime . "') OR ( TaskStartDate <= '" . $DisplayDate . "' ) )";

Comment: Actually, it turned out it needed this:
AND ( ( ( TaskCreated <= '2020-12-03 23:59:59' 
         OR ( TaskStartDate <= '2020-12-03' OR TaskStartDate = '' OR TaskStartDate is NULL ) )

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CASE statement in SQL

Comment: Turns on that that no CASE statement is needed. The query just needed another OR added.

Comment: I would have loved to see an example with a CASE statement. It would probably have been much easier to read than the current solution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get it to work as expected, you would need to change:

`$sql = $sql . " " . "AND ( TaskCreated <= '" . $DisplayDateTime . "'";`

to this:

```
$sql = $sql . " " . "AND ( ( TaskCreated <= '" . $DisplayDateTime . "'";    
$sql = $sql . " " . "OR ( TaskStartDate <= '" . $DisplayDate . "' OR TaskStartDate = '' OR TaskStartDate is NULL ) )";
```

This would show both tasks created on a certain date or started on a certain date and show tasks with no start date.

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM chReminders 
   WHERE TaskUserID = 1 
   AND ( ( ( TaskCreated <= '2020-12-03 23:59:59' 
         OR ( TaskStartDate <= '2020-12-03' OR TaskStartDate = '' OR TaskStartDate is NULL ) ) 
      AND ( TaskStartDate <= '2020-12-03' OR TaskStartDate = '' OR TaskStartDate is NULL ) 
      AND ( TaskPauseDate <= '2020-12-03' OR TaskPauseDate = '' OR TaskPauseDate is NULL ) 
      AND ( TaskSchedDate >= '2020-12-03' AND TaskSchedDate is NOT NULL ) 
      AND ( TaskDueDate >= '2020-12-03' OR TaskDueDate = '' OR TaskDueDate is NULL ) ) ) 
   AND ( TaskPauseDate <= '2020-12-03' OR TaskPauseDate = '' OR TaskPauseDate is NULL ) 
   ORDER BY TaskFocus DESC, TaskPriority ASC, TaskSchedDate ASC, TaskDueDate ASC
```